# How to automatically run a shell script when a file is saved in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I automatically run a shell script whenever I save a file in Visual Studio Code.
Right now I'm working on a project and I have written a shell script which will generate other files I need for the project. My question now is, how to automatically run the shell script every time I save changes to a particular file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a Gulp watchtask for this, they can easily be integrated with the task runner. There is a section in the VSCode docs that explain the basic setup here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_automating-markdown-compilation

The example is for Markdown compilation, but you can configure Gulp to execute you shell script. A working gulpfile.js would look somewhat like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var run = require('gulp-run');

gulp.task('script', function() {
    return run('./script.sh').exec();
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('./myFileToWatch.txt', ['script']);
})
```